# Blender 2.8 (Python) - resetting camera rotation to (0,0,0)

Tags: python, camera, transforms

I am trying to set the camera rotation to 0,0,0.  It is not known in advance what the X,Y,Z rotation angles are before doing so.

My thought is to get the current rotation parameters using `obj.rotation_euler` and then doing a reverse rotation on each of the axes.

For some reason, the transform.rotate code below doesn't actually do anything.

Thanks in advance for your help!

```
obj=bpy.data.objects['Camera']    
objrot=obj.rotation_euler
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-objrot[0], orient_axis='X', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=True, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-objrot[1], orient_axis='Y', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=True, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
bpy.ops.transform.rotate(value=-objrot[2], orient_axis='Z', orient_type='GLOBAL', orient_matrix=((1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)), orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', constraint_axis=(False, True, False), mirror=True, use_proportional_edit=True, proportional_edit_falloff='SMOOTH', proportional_size=1, use_proportional_connected=False, use_proportional_projected=False)
```

Comment: Martin's answer is the way to go. Note that setting camera rotationn to 0,0,0 means it will point straight down (i.e. looking negatively along the Z-axis)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`bpy.context.scene.camera.rotation_euler = (0,0,0)`